# ECS privileged container non root user cannot user docker Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker, terraform, amazon-ecs, terragrunt

The ongoing issues is related to using a non root user inside the container.

On my local pc, I am using the exact same image and forging start with the created user.

Dockerfile:

```
RUN groupadd "runner" && useradd -g "runner" --shell /bin/bash "runner" \
    && mkdir -p "/home/runner" \
    && chown -R "runner":"runner" "/home/runner"
RUN usermod -aG docker "runner"

WORKDIR /home/runner
USER runner
```

From my terminal (local pc) I can run the docker version command with user runner:

```
❯ docker run --user runner -ti -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock github-runner-entrypoint:0.8 /bin/bash
runner@62514eaea867:~$ /usr/bin/docker version --format '{{.Server.APIVersion}}'
1.41
runner@62514eaea867:~$
```

From ECS task, I get an error that I the user does not have sufficient privileges:

terraform:

User declaration under container_definitions:

```
 user = "runner"

Command-line parameters:

          entrypoint = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
          command = ["/bin/mount && /bin/docker run debian:latest /bin/ls"]
```

If I disable the  user = "runner" I can successfully run the docker command.

Please can you see anything wrong on my side here or am I missing some extra parameter please ?

Comment: Please add reproducible code blocks to the question.

Comment: I can confim that on my local docker the /var/run/docker.sock mountpoint has srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Jul 31 09:46 /var/run/docker.sock permission but in ECS container it has no group permission srw-rw---- 1 root 994 0 Aug 3 10:51 /var/run/docker.sock. Maybe I need to find more options for the mountPoint ?

Comment: Do you know what _numeric_ group ID owns the Docker socket on the target system?  Does the user in the container have that same _numeric_ group?  (The `docker` name isn't relevant, only the _numeric_ group ID.)

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze I found a solution that is better than the ongoing issue with mounted volumes in ECS that is ongoing. Considering that my question got -1 here I presume that it is not relevant to put the solution here. Maybe I will update it in the github AWS repository in the following issue: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/938 . My solution is close to your question so I guess you already know

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is better than the ongoing issue with mounted volumes in ECS that is ongoing. Considering that my question got -1 here I presume that it is not relevant to put the solution here. Maybe I will update it in the github AWS repository in the following issue: github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/938 . My solution is close to your question so I guess